# Django UserCreationForm turning popup validation errors into in-line errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation, django-errors

I have created a user registration form using Django's inbuilt registration/validation, and I can't figure out how to modify the display of the popup style validation errors.

I've noticed that validation errors are displayed in two forms:

1. If any required field is not filled, or if the email field doesn't contain an '@' symbol, the validation error will be displayed in a popup message (screenshot 1).
2. If an error is not raised due to any of the reasons in (1), but for some other reason (i.e. passwords are too short or don't match; username is already taken), errors will be displayed in the form of an unordered list with class name 'errorlist' (screenshot 2, errors in dark red).

I don't really like the look of the popup style errors, and I would like to display them in the same way as the in-line errors. How should I go about doing this?

Form code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
```

HTML:

```
{% extends 'base/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/register.css' %}">
{% endblock css %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="content_holder"> 
        <div class="background"></div>
        <h1>Register</h1>

    <!-- Register form -->
    <form name='registration' method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        
        <div class ='line'>
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <h2>Εmail</h2>
            {{reg_form.email}}
            <div class='info'>{{reg_form.email.errors}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class ='line'>
            <h2>Username</h2>
            <div class='info'>at least 5 characters long, no spaces</div>
            {{reg_form.username}}
            <div class='info'>{{reg_form.username.errors}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class ='line'>
            <h2>Password</h2>
            <div class='info'>at least 8 characters long, no spaces</div>
            {{reg_form.password1}}
            <div class='info'>{{reg_form.password1.errors}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class ='line'>
            <h2>Confirm password</h2>
            <div class='info'></div>
            {{reg_form.password2}}
            <div class='info'>{{reg_form.password2.errors}}</div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="Create User">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Screenshot 1
[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2
[image: Screenshot 2, errors in red]

Comment: Those popup errors are not related to Django. That is just your browser doing some validation itself. If you don't want them to show up add the `novalidate` attribute to your form tag: `<form name='registration' method="POST" action="" novalidate>`

Comment: Thanks so much, embarassed that it was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "novalidate" to your form tag to remove the browser validation (pop up thingy). Then the Django form validation can show itself.

```
<form action="" method="" novalidate>
```